# When I submit larger file with AJAX jQuery to Laravel 5 controller, it getting empty data

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

When I try uploading an image file using jQuery ajax request to Laravel controller, the output in the controller is empty. But when I upload a small size file it's able to access but not the larger one. (I am using laravel version 5.7.*)

Note: I had updated my php.ini file for file uploading limits and post upload limits to 50M. Even though it's giving the same problem.

I had updated my php.ini file for file uploading limits and post upload limits to 50M. Even though it's giving the same problem.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'photo-upload',
    data: formData, // I had appended all the data to this FormData();
    success: function(result){
           swal("Success","Uploaded Successfully","success");
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

// Inside Controller

```
$photo = Input::file('photo'); // It's giving empty result with larger file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
$.ajax({
     url: "photo-upload",
     method:"POST",
     data: new FormData(this),
     // IF YOU WANT TO USE PROGRESS
     xhr: function() {
          var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
          if(myXhr.upload){
              // FUNCTIONS 
              myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
              myXhr.addEventListener("load", complete, false);
              myXhr.addEventListener("error", error, false);
              myXhr.addEventListener("abort", abort, false);
          }
          return myXhr;
      },
     dataType:'JSON',
     contentType: false,
     cache: false,
     processData: false,
     // IF SUCCESS
     success:function(data)
     {
        console.log(data);
     }
  });
```

2 - In your Controller :

```
protected function upload(Request $request) {
    // UPLOAD YOUR FILE HERE & INSERT DATA TO DATABASE
    $path = Storage::putFile('files', $request->file('photo')); // UPLOAD AND GET PATH

    // RETURN JSON DATA
    return response()->json([
           'file' => $path
    ]);
}
```

if you want to **use progress or any msg during upload**, that will help :

```
function progress(event){
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  var num = Math.round(percent);
  // SET THIS TO ANY DIV WITH JQUERY
}

function completeHandlerHome(event){
  // IF UPLOAD COMPLETED
}

function errorHandlerHome(event){
  // IF IS ERROR
}

function abortHandlerHome(event){
  // IF IS ABORTED
}
```

**It's work** for me :)

Comment: Still the problem has not resolved! It's allowing the smaller files but when try to upload large files it's giving the empty data in the controller.

Comment: It's from your code - I mean from php.ini for example or upload settings - Just verify your code - upload big files directly without ajax - and see if you get any ERROR :)